# ¿Es aconsejable editar una pregunta para dejarla mal?

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas, ediciones

La pregunta que ha llamado mi atención es : [¿Como puedo implementar esto en java? [cerrada]](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/11607/como-puedo-implementar-esto-en-java)

Esta pregunta ha sido editada por una persona distinta al autor. Y esa persona (@Jorgesys) posteriormente ha votado para cerrar esa pregunta. Entiendo que esto está en contra del criterio en [Centro de Ayuda > Privilegios > edit questions and answers](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)

> Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged - try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you observe.

Es evidente que esta persona no ha corregido todos los errores que ha observado pues si fuese así no hubiese votado para cerrar. No puedo más que pensar que esta persona considera que el resultado de su edición es una mala pregunta.

¿Son buenos estos tipos de ediciones? El centro de ayuda no dice que esté prohibido hacerlo, solo dice que no es aconsejable. ¿Es así? ¿Por qué?

Comment: No creo que sea exactamente así... Yo mismo edito preguntas para que sean *legibles* y *luego* puedo evaluar su estado. Seguramente fue así. Yo lo habría editado un poco más para corregirlo todo (la puntuación, especialmente) y luego hubiera votado para cerrar, después de dejar un comentario al OP.

Comment: [esta pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/22986/7242) por ejemplo, la he editado, he dejado un comentario y *luego* he votado para cerrarla. No creo que sea malo... Es una manera de entender mejor de qué va el tema para ayudar a decidir a uno mismo y a la comunidad qué hacer con esa pregunta.

Comment: Aclaro que es Jorgesys el que la cerró, así se entiende mejor el contexto.

Answer (score 9):

Según el [historial de ediciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/11607/revisions) de esa pregunta, lo único que se hizo fue indentar el código para que esté sobresaltado, lo cual no considero que sea una edición menor, en realidad me permite separar código de texto plano (en lo personal, eso me ayuda más a comprender los problemas en las preguntas). Dado ese contexto, la edición no creo que sea mala y facilita la lectura y comprensión de lo que se pide.

Ahora, tampoco se puede ser un súper héroe a la hora de editar la pregunta. A menos que seas adivino o tengas una esfera mágica de cristal, dudo que alguien pueda entrar en los pensamientos de una persona para comprender cuál es su necesidad en buena parte y poder plasmar el texto al respecto. Viéndolo de ese lado, lo más que se podía hacer al editar la pregunta era indentar el código. Intentar agregar información que no sabemos si el OP quería o no puede ensuciar la publicación en lugar de ayudar a que sea "mejor" (esto depende mucho de la perspectiva con que se mire). Se debe tener mucho cuidado al agregar información en una publicación, sobretodo si el OP no ha brindado dicha información y se esté "inventando". Para evitar esto, lo preferible es colocar comentarios a la pregunta y utilizar las respuestas de los comentarios del OP para editar la pregunta.

Más bien, veo que ninguno de los votantes a cierre comentó para pedir aclaraciones. Eso me preocupa más en la comunidad. Pero ese problema está fuera del alcance de esta pregunta.

Comment: "Dado ese contexto, la edición no creo que sea mala y facilita la lectura y comprensión de lo que se pide" . Yo no he dicho lo contrario. Lo que he dicho es que "el resultado de su edición es una mala pregunta." Es decir, la pregunta después de la edición es una mala pregunta; mejor que antes, pero sigue siendo mala. Respecto al comentario para pedir aclaraciones ya lo hiciste tu, seguramente ninguno vio necesidad de repetir tus palabras, no es ese el problema en absoluto.

Comment: Entiendo entonces, según las palabras del moderador, que hacer ediciones que se limitan a mejorar la identación se considera una buena práctica en SOes.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos eso lo veo desde SO. Y veo que aquí también eso resulta positivo. Para lo que sigue, que la pregunta "sigue siendo mala", está el segundo párrafo.

Answer (score 3):

Entiendo que el caso específico señalado tiene como propósito ser un ejemplo para ayudar a explicar el tema expuesto. En la respuesta previa se señalan cosas muy puntuales. A continuación abordo el tema de forma general.

Voy a empezar por refrasear la pregunta

> ¿Es aconsejable editar una pregunta cuando esa edición no es suficiente para hacerla una buena pregunta y luego ser votada para cerrar por el mismo editor?

**En síntesis**, lo ideal es que al editar una pregunta se corrijan todos los problemas, cuando no es posible, si esa edición facilitará ediciones futuras ya sea por el OP u otro editor, **considero que debe realizarse**.

Los motivos para corregir todos los problemas al realizar una edición podrían ser varios, el que tengo presente en este momento es:

1. Minimizar las entradas en el historial de revisiones, lo cual a su vez facilita el seguimiento de la evolución de una pregunta, así como acciones subsecuentes, como reversión, o discusión sobre la revisión realizada.

Los efectos de una edición, dependiendo de las circunstancias y puntos de vista podrían llevar a calificar la edición como benéfica, perjudicial o inocua.

Recordemos que el editar una pregunta hace que se "reflote", es decir, se mostrará en la parte superior temporalmente en la página de inicio y en las vistas de actividad reciente, además el OP recibirá una notificación, y dependiendo de los privilegios del editor, podría pasar la pregunta a las colas de revisión. Esto podría llamar la atención a la pregunta tanto del OP como de otros usuarios, de hecho, esto se recomienda en [¿Qué debo hacer si nadie contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers)

Si esto es bueno, malo  o "ni fú ni fá" depende de cada caso e particular.

Por ejemplo, según entiendo, no existe un límite en términos prácticos sobre el número de revisiones que se pueden realizar a una publicación, así que una edición, no hace "mella", pero múltiples ediciones que no mejoran una publicación si bien no bloquearán ediciones futuras, podrían dificultar el seguimiento de su evolución.

Si la pregunta no ha tenido ediciones previas, considero que una edición no dificultará por sí misma el seguimiento, así que no le veo problema, lo que es distinto al caso en el que se han hecho varias ediciones con anterioridad, en cuyo caso, debería pensarse con cuidado el hacer o no la edición que se tiene en mente.

Ahora bien, el discutir la secuencia de acciones de moderación, en específico editar para luego votar para cerrar, es complicado. Por un lado, una pregunta cerrada eventualmente podría ser eliminada. Alguno podrá argumentar que esto es un pérdida de tiempo, pero otro puede decir que es una forma de hacer un ***llamado*** a prestar atención a la pregunta **más fuerte** que el de la edición.

Comment: ¡Bien dicho! A mí me gusta pensar que las ediciones sirven para pulir piedras que pueden llegar a diamante. En cambio, no toco nada si sospecho que lo que tengo delante es un pedrusco.